# Reset password in Django

Tags: python, django

I have view this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6pXNf2SzQQ that explain how to send mail to reset password, I have follow all steps but I have the same error always: No module named 'my_app.views.django'; 'my_app.views' is not a package. For this case my_app = melomanos. I have all templates for Django reset password in my site templates folder.

**The complete site root is:**

[image: root of my app]

**The error that shows is:** I know I have a missconfigured urls but I don't understand how I can configure correctly. Thanks for your cooperation.

```
ImportError at /resetpassword/
No module named 'melomanos.views.django'; 'melomanos.views' is not a package
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/resetpassword/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'melomanos.views.django'; 'melomanos.views' is not a package
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module, line 109
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:['c:\\labsoft',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6-py3.4-win-amd64.egg',
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages',
'labsoft/melomanos',
'/melomanos']
```

here is the codes:

**melomanos\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import Buscar_view
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('melomanos.views',
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^$','trabajos_all_view',name='url_index'),
                   url(r'^register/$','register_view',name='vista_registro'),
                   url(r'^login/$','login_view',name='vista_login'),
                   url(r'^logout/$','logout_view',name='vista_logout'),
                   url(r'^perfil/$','registro_view',name='vista_perfil'),
                   url(r'^publicar/$','trabajomusical_view', name='vista_publicar'),
                   url(r'^trabajos/$','trabajos_view',name='vista_trabajos'),
                   url(r'^trabajo/(?P<id_trabajo>.*)/$','solo_trabajo_view', name='vista_trabajo'),
                   url(r'^buscar/$',Buscar_view.as_view(),name='vista_buscar'),
                   url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
                   url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
                   url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
                   url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
                   url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
                   )
```

**The link at the login page:**

```
<p>Forgot your password?<a href="/resetpassword/">Reset Password</a></p>
```

**settings.py**

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'melomanos',
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `melomanos\urls.py` you are using url prefix.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('melomanos.views',
    url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
)
```

So `/resetpassword/` is calling `melomanos.views.django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset` instead of `django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset`

For reset password view removing the prefix will solve this issue.

You may remove `resetpassword` from prefixed block and later add it without prefix like

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
)
```

Comment: if Automagically fixed all pages. I have a new question the page for the request email is showed perfectly, I write my mail and the paga says the restore password was sent successfully but, in my inbox there is nothing, I don't received the restore link. here is my settings.py and I'm secure is right.  EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'melomanos@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'the password'#is not the pass.
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True ----- May I have to do another configurations??.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR;** - do not reference views as strings - import related module and pass view function instead. In this case, you don't need to use `prefix`.

### Some historical notes:

Long time ago, Django released `url` function, where you can define the path to required view, passing a string. There were a lot of views with same prefix, that is why Django team also provides `prefix` argument in `django.conf.urls.patterns()` function, which allows you to extract mutual part of view paths.

### Today, this is no more than relic.

Now you should import views inside your `urls.py` module and use functions directly. There is no more reason for `prefix` argument.

Moreover, since Django 1.8 the `patterns` function is deprecated and will be removed in Django 2.0:

```
def patterns(prefix, *args):
    warnings.warn(
        'django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in '
        'Django 2.0. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of '
        'django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.',
        RemovedInDjango20Warning, stacklevel=2
    )
    # Implementation
```

Instead, you should just pass a list of your patterns like this ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns)):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.myview),
    url('^other/$', views.otherview),
]
```